# Does Android log any details about full system crashes?

Tags: cyanogenmod

My Samsung S3, which I rooted and flashed with Cyanogenmod 10.2 will randomly fully crash, and require a reboot (Power + Volume down for ~10 seconds). This seems to happen randomly, when just scrolling through a list, loading a webpage, sometimes when it's not even doing anything.

I'm wondering if any logs are stored anywhere which I can look at to see if there is one underlying issue causing these crashes.

This doesn't seem to be something that I can make happen, up to now I've not found something that will **always** crash the device.

EDIT: It actually doesn't seem to be a full crash, just a UI one. It's just happen now viewing a webpage, and I can't lock the device, scroll, no buttons do anything, but Spotify was playing a song in the background and that continued playing.

Answer (score 0):

connect your device through usb and run below ADB command

`adb shell logcat`

this will show you all the activity start from the device power up to now

edit: this kind of problems occurred on me when my emmc bricked, when device try to use specific part of emmc which has bad block device stuck and cant do anything but voice continue to come

Comment: I'll give that a try when I get in from work (can't install the SDK on the PC's here)

Comment: dont need whole sdk just adb and fastboot you can download them seperately, google it